# Change update check time?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I barely use Windows 10 (I use Linux mostly) but every now an then (say once a week) I need to go on windows either for MS Office or Skype (SkypeforLinux being a joke of a software).
But because it doesn't turn on often, windows gets crazy on start up and it becomes slow (after 10 minutes it runs smooth). I checked and at the beginning Windows updates goes ballistic on trying to get updates.
Is there a way to change how often it looks for updates? Say once a month (so I only see this effect once a month), or maybe 2 hours after the restart? Or maybe it never checks for updates but I do it manually (I'd still want it to give me a notification so I remember).

Comment: You can change and/or configure the active hours you want Windows to actually install updates, but that really won't do you much good, unless Windows is your daily OS.  Updates are required in Windows 10.  Windows Update will not check for updates if you indicate you are connected to a metered connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Windows system checks for updates randomly(every 17 to 22 hours).

If you want to custom update detection time on Windows 10, you can disable Windows Update via disabling Windows Update service:
Open RUN, type “***services.msc***” and end with enter, find **Windows Update** service and manually disable it.
[image]

Then, manually start Windows Update service when you need to check/download/install Windows Update.

For Windows 10, there is new update concept - cumulative updates, where each update released contains all the new fixes for that month, as well as all the older fixes from previous months. So, just install the latest and only one/several update each month.

You can check and find detail update release information via **Windows 10 update history**:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4043454

So, except for checking update via system built-in Windows Update, you can just manually download and install update for your system each month.

However, automatically Windows Update is always recommended as it will detach available update periodically/ regularly, and make sure that your system is fully patched.

Comment: Thanks. If it's meant to be always updated maybe Ill just leave as it is. I thought there would be a normal way of changing this. Its a pitty because I dont dislike windows, I use linux for work, but I am bound to have a bad experience with windows as I use it rarelly..

Comment: Only people who have a bad experience with Windows are people who forcefully disable Windows Update, and then get hit by Ransomware because they didn’t have a patch installed that was released weeks earlier OEM In this example 2 months.